# Где правильнее выполнять установку значения свойства, в сеттере или в конструкторе класса?

Tags: c#, properties

```
public abstract class Parser
{
    protected List<string> Tables { get; set; }
    protected string TableName { get; }
    public List<List<object>> Table { get; protected set; }

    public Parser()
    {
        Tables = GetListOfTables();
        Program.PrintCollection(Tables);
        TableName = Program.GetUserChoose(Tables);
        Table = GetTable();
    }

    protected abstract List<string> GetListOfTables();
    protected abstract List<List<object>> GetTable();
}
```

Как правильнее присваивать значения свойствам, в конструкторе, или напрямую в сеттере свойства? Мне кажется, более логично сразу в свойстве, но ведь можно и в конструкторе задать. Возможно, есть какие-то негласные правила? Посмотрев описания встроенных классов, не нашел много случаев, когда свойства задаются сразу.

Comment: `publc` -> `public`

Comment: [Тыц](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.4.php) и [тыц](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties).

Comment: Начните с того, что конструктор не должен делать всяких `PrintCollection`. Конструктор должен инициализировать свой объект, поля и свойства, и больше ничего.

Comment: Конструктор всё-таки не для сложной логики. Я бы такую логику как у вас вынес в отдельный статический метод, который создаёт новый экземпляр класса и заполняет его поля. Ну и возвращает этот экземпляр. Только с наследованием ещё разобраться, не соображу как, а то бы ответ оформил.

Comment: Тут нужно задаться вопросом: мутабельный у нас объект или нет? Наличие сеттера позволит менять значение извне. Возможно, это не нужно и даже вредно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не существует "правильного способа" установления значений свойствам.

В конструкторе можно установить начальное значение. В большинстве случаев это удобно, когда значения передаются через параметры. Если же у вас очень много свойств, то передавать все в конструктор неудобно, тогда логичнее оставить конструктор пустым и задавать свойства напрямую.

Answer (score 2):

Я согласен с ответом @iiKuzmychov, но не до конца. Иногда бывают классы, которые без каких-либо данных не имеют смысла, так же преимущество конструктора перед `set` - вызов каких либо методов в этом конструкторе (что очень нежелательно, но всё же). Помимо вызова чего-либо проверять на валидность данных тоже лучше делать в конструкторе, нежели в `set`, т.к придётся делать `backing field` (можете сами посмотреть на читаемость кода с проверкой в `set` и конструкторе). Смысл конструктора - инициализировать объект, не больше.

```
class File
{
   public File(string path)
   {
       if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
         throw new ArgumentNullException();

       Path = path;
   }
   public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

В C# 9 добавили [`init`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/init) свойства и это работает следующим образом:

```
class MyClass //Можно использовать record
{ 
   public int MyIntProperty { get; init; }
}
```

```
var myClass = new MyClass() { MyIntProperty = 5 };
```

Comment: Но если делать проверку в конструкторе, как в вашем примере `File`, то ничто не мешает после этого изменить свойство, будь оно с пубоичным `set` или `init`

Comment: `var file = new File("path");` и `file.Path = null`

Comment: И, к слову, с# 12 обещает облегчить создание "backing field", вводя ключевое слово `field`

Comment: @iiKuzmychov да, пример не супер хороший, но я думаю он объясняет главный смысл конструктра - инициализация поля. Слышал про C# 12, - жду с нетерпением чтобы апдейтнуться и затестить новый сахар :)